# How to transfer Textures From blender to maya

Tags: texturing, materials, export

I have a character that it's highly textured in blender 2.9. I'm gonna have to export this character to Maya for animation. How can I export the textures and materials? Do I have to bake them? Do I have to use UDIMs?

Comment: How is your model textured in Blender? Have you UV unwrapped and painted textures in texture paint mode? Have you used vertex colors? Have you built a node-based shader? What exactly have you done, and what exactly do you want to end up with?

Comment: I still didn't start texturing the character in Blender. I wanted to start the right way so I don't end up with problems after I send the model to Maya for animation. I'm going to unwrap the character the body alone and the clothes alone. Then I'm gonna paint them using texture paint. And I'm gonna use nodes to add the painted textures, normal maps and adjust the roughness and all the settings.

Comment: The texturing process is going to be in Blender and that same character has to transferred to Maya for animation.